# Webpack with babel and handlebars files

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs

REVISED
So I am fairly new to this and I am struggling for some time to resolve this, so I would really appreciate help.

**Goal:** Create dynamic web-page that is using handlebars and D3 for dynamic text and visuals.

**What I achieved until now:** Use json file stored within to do some data manipulation and render data with hbs and express. Created simple bar chart that uses data from the previous file.

**Issue:** I am not sure how to completely set up webpack so I can actually see how my page looks like. If I just add script with D3 visuals to hbs I am getting require is not defined, which I get since it's not supported on client side.

folder structure

```
|main
  |data
    |data.json
  |src
    |index.js
    |visuals.js
  |templates
    |views
      |index.hbs
  |node_modules
  |package.json
  |package-lock.json
  |webpack.config.js
  |babel.config.json
```

My code until now (there might be to many things here because I tried a lot of things plus I was anonymizing as I have sensitive items)

index.js:

```
  const express = require("express");
   const fs = require("fs");
   const path = require("path");
   const hbs = require("hbs");
    
   const Data = JSON.parse(
      fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "../data/data.json")).toString()
    );
    
    //Some data manipulation
    
   module.exports = clusters; //array to be used in the other file
    
   const app = express();
   const publicDirectoryPath = path.join(__dirname, "..");
   const viewPath = path.join(__dirname, "../templates/views");
    
   app.set("view engine", "hbs");
   app.set("views", viewPath);
   app.use(express.static(publicDirectoryPath));
    
   app.get("", (req, res) => {
     res.render("index", {
       data1: data1,
       data2:data2,
     });
   });
```

Beginning of visuals.js

```
const d3 = require("d3"); 
var dt = require("./index.js");
const clusters = dt.clusters;
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const HandlebarsPlugin = require("handlebars-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/visuals.js"),
    path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/index.js"),
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./public"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.handlebars$/, loader: "handlebars-loader" },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {//I had errors and warnings with modules, below solved it
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname), "node_modules/"],
    extensions: [".js", ".json"],
    descriptionFiles: ["package.json"],
    },
    fallback: {
      stream: false,
      http: false,
      buffer: false,
      crypto: false,
      zlib: false,
      fs: false,
      net: "empty",
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new HandlebarsPlugin({//can't say I understood from documentation the setup for hbs
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "./templates/views/index.hbs"),

      output: path.resolve(__dirname, "./public/index.html"),

      data: path.resolve(__dirname, "./data/data.json"),

      onBeforeSetup: function (Handlebars) {},
      onBeforeCompile: function (Handlebars, templateContent) {},
      onBeforeRender: function (Handlebars, data, filename) {},
      onBeforeSave: function (Handlebars, resultHtml, filename) {},
      onDone: function (Handlebars, filename) {},
    }),
  ],
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "triana_plus",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "start": "webpack serve --config ./webpack.config.js --open chrome"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.10",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "handlebars-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack": "^5.10.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^2.5.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "d3": "^6.3.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "handlebars-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "hbs": "^4.1.1",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "request": "^2.88.2"
  }
}
```

babel.config.json

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

Comment: "I tried Webpack and Browserify but without success, I guess I am setting it up wrong as I am getting errors." That is your problem. Perhaps open a SO post about fixing those errors

Comment: @Pytth thanks, I changed the question, I just need to run npm install npm@latest -g first so I could install webpack

Comment: Have you run `npm i` in your project? Do you have webpack-cli installed?

Comment: @Pytth yes I followed https://www.robinwieruch.de/webpack-setup-tutorial for help, as it looked simple enough

Comment: @Pytth is lodash something that is necessary to install and add to scripts? I am seeing it in official documentation https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/

Comment: No, it isn't necessary. lodash is a library of convenience methods. I think they are just using it as an example.

Comment: You should post the errors themselves instead of summarizing them.

Comment: @Jacob I added an example. There are 22 of errors, they are the similar, so no reason to add all of them.

Answer (score 0):

What the error you posted means is that webpack is being asked to create some JS bundles that reference *node* packages like `http`. Referencing packages like that in client-side code bundles won't work since it cannot package node modules in the JS artifacts.

Make sure that no node-specific packages are required/imported for files you're bundling through webpack. Since it looks like you're creating an express app, keep the express-specific files outside of the folder visited by webpack.

Comment: thanks. I am new to this, so I hope I will not say something stupid. The whole reason for webpack was for me to use d3 that is built from the data that I transform through other files. If I just simply add that script to the html I get "require is not defined" error. I have "require" to load data and use d3 library so I don't need to add the link. That is why I wanted to go with webpack. I didn't went far enough to to see if I will need to use "Require" again. If I use import I get that "import is outside of module".

Comment: If you're using webpack, you should be able to use `require` since it will know then to bundle it as a dependency. `import` would work if you were using babel, but that's a whole slew of additional things you'd have to learn so stick with `require` for now.